# Exporting / Importing a Const from a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, constants, export

I have read several Stack Overflow questions and articles trying to find a simple example of what I'm trying to do, but everything seems overly complicated. I just want to be able to export a const that I created in a function in one React component, and import for use into another React component. For example:

Component containing the `const` I want to export, `FirstArticle`:

```
function Articles() {
  const FirstArticle = document.querySelector('.article');
  console.log(FirstArticle) // <div class="article">Article 1</div>

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="article">Article 1</div>
      <div class="article">Article 2</div>
      <div class="article">Article 3</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Articles;
```

Component into which I want to import the `const FirstArticle`:

```
import Articles, { FirstArticle } from "./Articles";

function Preview() {
  return (
    <div>
      {FirstArticle} // Would expect to see: <div class="article">Article 1</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Preview;
```

I have tried a few different things - moving the `const FirstArticle` to outside of the `Articles` function to make it more "global", putting the const in a separate function and exporting/importing that function (works but it imports the whole function on the other component and I'm not sure how to parse out just the `FirstArticle` const), and exporting the const in the `export default` line along with the function (didn't work).

I'm reading that I may need to use `useState`. As I'm new to React I'm not too familiar with this. Is `useState` the solution I need to look into?

Comment: You can use `useRef` hook here. Rest can tell you if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. If you like you can use https://codesandbox.io/ . This will make easier to understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: I definitely need to research more about useRef. It seems that is what most articles say but I was hoping there was an easy way to do this without hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use different files for the different components? Something like:

```js
// useArticles.js
export function useArticles() {
  return [...something]; // the array of articles
}
```

```js
// Article.js
export function Article(props) {
  const {article} = props;
  return <div class="article">
    {/* ...here you render a single article */}
  </div>;
}
```

```js
// Articles.js
import { Article } from './Article';
import {useArticles} from './useArticles';
export function Articles() {
  const articles = useArticles();
  return <div>
    {articles.map(article => <Article key={article.id} article={article} />)}
  </div>;
}
```

```js
// Preview.js
import {Article} from './Article';
import {useArticles} from './useArticles';
function Preview() {
  const articles = useArticles();
  const firstArticle = articles[0];
  return (
    <div>
      <Article article={firstArticle} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Preview;
```

Btw, if you are new to react and you don't know `useState` I suggest you to learn the react hooks before proceed (particularly `useState` and `useEffect`).

Also, in react you should always think to the data first and after how to render them, it will be better to avoid getting data from render components when it's possible.

Comment: I see what you are saying. For my particular use case, these "articles" are actually dynamic. That is, every time I add a new article div, I add to the top of the list of articles. So "FirstArticle" today may not be the same as the "FirstArticle" tomorrow. That is why I would like to pull the FirstArticle from the "Articles" component where all of the articles live rather than use a separate component, if that makes sense. It seems like I really just need to dive into these hooks though. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Ok, I suppose the articles are in an array coming from API, right?

Comment: No API, just my own content. Each "article" is a preview of a blog I have written, so the "article" is a div that contains a headline, image, and short sentence summarizing the blog. But yes, I can access as an array and so the const I'm trying to export could either be the whole array (import into another component and then target just the first array object to show), or I can separate out the first article from the array into its own const first and then just export that, as that is the only part I really need to use on the other component.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: Your new edit looks like it could work for me now. That's a clever workaround to avoid using the hooks I'm unfamiliar with. Let me try applying to my code. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, but this is not a workaround, that's the proper way to do it in react: based on the data first and the render the component. Little spoiler: the method I've created (`useArticles`) is a custom hook, and if you just start to use react now I really suggest you to look into the [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html).